# Pandas Styler Hiding Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I basically want a table that has right-justified table cell entries and a minimum column width of 100. I have two ways to display a Pandas dataframe `df` in HTML:

```
html = df.style.applymap(color_negative_red).set_precision(5).set_table_attributes(
    'class = "dataframe table-bordered table-striped table-hover').set_properties(
        **{'width': '10em', 'text-align': 'right'}).render()

display(HTML(html)
```

In this method, I can't figure out how to hide the row indices using the Styler object (i.e., there is no `index = False` parameter I could set before I render.

and:

```
return df.to_html(index=ind, justify = {"right"}, col_space = 100,
                  classes = ["table-bordered", "table-striped", "table-hover"])
```

This method, using `to_html`, does not seem to work with the `justify` and `col_space` parameters.

How can I go about doing this/find a workaround to either problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think `hide_index()` may help with dropping the index on your first method. From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html#Hiding-the-Index-or-Columns),

> The index can be hidden from rendering by calling `Styler.hide_index`. Columns can be hidden from rendering by calling `Styler.hide_columns` and passing in the name of a column, or a slice of columns.

So the following should work,

```
....
.hide_index().render()
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be helpful if you could link to e.g. some documentation, or explain why this would work.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html, "The index can be hidden from rendering by calling Styler.hide_index. Columns can be hidden from rendering by calling Styler.hide_columns and passing in the name of a column, or a slice of columns."

I wasn't aware of this myself till this week, looks like the OP and I have been googling the same sort of problems.

Comment: This is now deprecated and the preferred solution is currently `.hide(axis="index")`